# React native Flatlist navigate to diffrent page

Tags: react-native

```
import React from 'react';
import { FlatList, StyleSheet, Text, View , ScrollView ,TouchableHighlight,TouchableOpacity,Touchable} from 'react-native';
import { useState } from 'react';

function HomeContent({navigation}){
    const [Level, setLevel] = useState([
        {name:'ม.3\nปี59', key:1},
        {name:'ม.3\nปี60', key:2},
        {name:'ม.3\nปี61', key:3},
        {name:'ม.3\nปี62', key:4},
        {name:'ม.3\nปี63', key:5},
        {name:'ม.6\nปี59', key:6},
        {name:'ม.6\nปี60', key:7},
        {name:'ม.6\nปี61', key:8},
        {name:'ม.6\nปี62', key:9},
        {name:'ม.6\nปี63', key:10},
    ])

    const pressHandler = () => {
        var i;
        for (i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
            navigation.navigate(`Exam${i}`) /*exam.{key_page}*/ 
        }
    }

    return(
        <View style = {styles.mainContent}>
            <ScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator ={false}>
            <FlatList 
                data = {Level}
                renderItem = {({item}) => (
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress= {pressHandler}>
                    <View style = {styles.mainContentBox} >
                        <Text style={styles.mainContentBoxText}>{item.name}</Text>
                    </View>    
                    
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                )}
                numColumns = {2}
            />
            </ScrollView>
        </View>
    )
}
```

I have many Exam pages (Exam[1-10]) how to navigate to a different page I try to use for loop the number but it doesn't work that make me go to all page 1-10

I am a newbie sorry if this is obvious

Comment: Can you elaborate on the problem and provide the expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way

```
const pressHandler = (item) => {
   navigation.navigate(`Exam${item.key}`);
}


<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { pressHandler(item)} >
  <View style = {styles.mainContentBox} >
      <Text style={styles.mainContentBoxText}>{item.name}</Text>
  </View>           
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: ` <TouchableOpacity onPress= {() => {navigation.navigate(`Exam${item.key}`)}}>`     it's worked Thx ^_^

Answer (score 0):

get index prop from `renderItem` and navigate

```
renderItem = {({item,index}) => (
     <TouchableOpacity onPress= {() => {
       const pageNumber = index+1;
      navigation.navigate(`Exam${pageNumber}`) /*exam.{key_page}*/ 
     }}>
    .....
```